# Doctrine query with nullable/optional join

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got a method on my repository class to get me `Article` with their join (category, image ...) and not every `Article` have categories or image, what don't give me back all expected result, cause my current repository function return only `Article` who have `Categories` and `Image` not null and just ignore what having null value.

My `Article` entity have the following relationship.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\ArticleBundle\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $categories;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\ArticleBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 */
private $image;
```

And this is my repository function

```
public function getArticle($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->where('a.id = :theId')
        ->setParameter('theId', $id)
    ->join('a.author', 'auth')
        ->addSelect('auth')
    ->join('a.categories', 'cat')
        ->addSelect('cat')
    ->join('a.image', 'img')
        ->addSelect('img');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Now I want to know if I can get `Article` which have `categories`, `image` or not in one query with the join. I want to say when using the Doctrine lazy loading (by avoid the join in the query) I get the expected result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `->leftJoin()` to get `Article` which has `categories`, `image` or not in one query:

```
public function getArticle($id)
{
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->addSelect('auth', 'cat', 'img')
        ->join('a.author', 'auth')
        ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'cat')
        ->leftJoin('a.image', 'img')
        ->where('a.id = :theId')
        ->setParameter('theId', $id)
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Thus, this avoids extra queries when Doctrine attempts to load the related properties in a lazy manner.

Explanation:

Using `->join()` or `->innerJoin()`:

[image]

> This is the simplest, most understood Join and is the most common. This query will return all of the records in the left table (table A) that have a matching record in the right table (table B).

Using `->leftJoin()`:

[image]

> This query will return all of the records in the left table (table A) regardless if any of those records have a match in the right table (table B). It will also return any matching records from the right table.

Source: **[Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)** explained in detail by **[C.L. Moffatt](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=5909363)**

Comment: Just wanted to say nice answer and +1 for the diagrams

Comment: thx, it work, i admit that i have some prob with the different join, i've many graphic like this who explain it but it was never clear but the above link is great way to earn more about, respect